# Converting sql to lambda expression or Linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Hi I have following sql statement I want to convert it to lambda expression or linq

```
select
a.lid
,a.name
,a.notes
,lrh.e
,lrh.date
from rate a 
left outer join lab_history lrh on(lrh.lab_id=a.lid)
```

Please let me know how to change this to lambda expression or linq. Thanks

Comment: [101 LINQ Samples - Left outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query:

```
from a in db.rate
join lrh db.lab_history on a.lid equals lrh.lab_id 
into lrhs
from lrh in lrhs.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new 
   {
      lid = a.lid,
      ... another props
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
   var labRateObj = (from a in ContextObj.rate 
       join lrh in ContextObj.lab_history on a.lid equals lrh.lab_id into labrate
       from s in labrate.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new {
    lid = a.lid,
    name = a.name,
    notes = a.notes,
    e = lrh.e,
    date = lrh.date

    });
```